# JavaScript event when user come back to page from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, browser

I have list of links which created dynamically from server. When user clicks one it will opens tab in new window. So, question is there any javascript event which will be triggered when user will come back from newly created tab to first page with links?

Comment: Listen `focus` on `window`, though it fires also when the page is first loaded.

Comment: When listening `focus`, that should be attached by the native `addEventListener`, if you're using jQuery events, you need to check that the target is `window`, since all events are bubbling in jQuery event model, while the native `focus` event doesn't bubble.

Answer (score 0):

I think a first thing you need to do is to first store the links to either local storage, cache or sessions depending on the language/technology that you use on back-end, then whenever a page load or reloads you'll need to listen for a **load** event  `window.addEventListener('load', callBackFunction)` using javascript because i think this is what you prefer.

**NB:** *I think it would be of much help if you could share some codes on how links are presented from server side scripts and the scripting language you use on back-end.*